# Is there a way for variables to have a few types in GDScript

Tags: variables, types, option-type, godot, gdscript

I know GDScript has dynamic typing, but I was wondering if there was a way to give a variable only a few types it can have. Something like this:

```
var myVar : int : string = 12;
myVar = "Hello";
```

Does it have a feature like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This is not supported in GDScript.

There is a relevant proposal: https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues/737 (The syntax would be `var myVar: int|string`). However, it is not part of the Godot 4.0 milestone.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks for answering! 